# How to get curl output of uploaded file details after file upload

Tags: php, laravel, curl, libcurl, php-curl

I need to get uploaded id from ftps after file upload using curl. Right now it return true or false. I need curl response of file upload.
My Current Code :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftpServer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,env('SFTP_USER').':'.env('SFTP_PASSWORD'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
$resultInfo = curl_exec($ch);
```

But $resultInfo return 1.
I need full information like uploaded id, file path etc.
Please can anyone help on this?

Comment: CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER will output the return data that comes from the server. So, in your case, for getting the id, you server where you are uploading the file, it should return the id. Otherwise you will not see the Id